# Reachability and Status in IOS

Tags: ios, ios7, reachability

I have the following code in my viewController.m class:

```
     - (void) testInternetConnection
{
    internetConnection = [Reachability reachabilityWithHostname:@"www.google.com"];

    // Internet is reachable
    internetConnection.reachableBlock = ^(Reachability*reach)
    {
        // Update the UI on the main thread
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            NSLog(@"Yayyy, we have the interwebs!");
        });
    };

    // Internet is not reachable
    internetConnection.unreachableBlock = ^(Reachability*reach)
    {
        // Update the UI on the main thread
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            NSLog(@"Someone broke the internet :(");
        });
    };

    [internetConnection startNotifier];
}
```

1. How do I use the startNotifier?
2. Do I have to put this in every view controller I want to test internet connectivity in?

I use this to test the status:

```
BOOL status = ([[Reachability reachabilityForInternetConnection] currentReachabilityStatus] != NotReachable);
```

Answer (score 2):

startNotifier means after that any network state changed will notify whoever register the kReachabilityChangedNotification notification.

You don't have to put this in every view controller.

1、You need a singleton instance and has a member value which is used to keep network state.

2、Register the kReachabilityChangedNotification notification , handle it and get network state and store it in your member value and Post Notification(custom notificaiton) to notify others(your viewcontroller).

3、Provide interfaces to get the current network state so that your viewcontrollers will know the network state when network state changed.

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your app delegate class.

write this code in application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions.

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver: self selector: @selector(reachabilityChanged:) name: kReachabilityChangedNotification object: nil];
Reachability  *hostReachable = [[Reachability reachabilityWithHostName: @"www.google.com"] retain];
[hostReachable startNotifier];
```

Write this methods in your Appdelegate class.

```
- (void) reachabilityChanged: (NSNotification* )note
   {
    Reachability* curReach = [note object];
        [self updateInterfaceWithReachability: curReach];
   }


- (void) updateInterfaceWithReachability: (Reachability*) curReach
   {
     if(curReach == hostReachable)
       {
            NetworkStatus netStatus = [curReach currentReachabilityStatus];
             if (netStatus == 0 )
              {
                NSLog(@"offline");
              }
             else
              {
                NSLog(@"online");
              }
        }
    }
```